# Screen Resizing for lottie animation in React js

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks, lottie

I am working on a website that has a lottie animation on it's landing page, how do i resize the lottie component such that display is set to none on mobile devices.

lottie component below

```
import React from "react";
import Lottie from "react-lottie";
import data from "./Lottie/87736-car-animation.json";

export default function App() {
  const defaultOptions = {
loop: true,
autoplay: true,
animationData: data,
rendererSettings: {
  preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice",
    },
  };

  return (
<div id="lottie">
  <Lottie
    options={defaultOptions}
    height={800}
    width={1000}
    style={{
      top: "30%",
      right: "10%",
      zIndex: -1,
      overflow: "hidden",
      position: "fixed",
    }}
  />
</div>
  );
}
```

here is the home component.

```
import Lottie from "../Components/Lottie";
import React from "react";

function Landing () => {
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  if (width > 600px) {
console.log(width);
  } else {
document.getElementById("lottie").style.display = "none";
   }
  <Lottie className="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 lottie d-none" />
}

export default Landing;
```

I also tried using external CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .lottie {
display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the thing is, with react you can conditionally render components without having to use native dom manipulations such as `document.getElementById`.

First, let's try to simplify the way you get your windows size :
Create some kind of exported function that you can reuse somewhere else
**windowDimensions.js**

```js
export function getWindowDimensions() {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return {
    width,
    height
  };
}
```

Then import it in your App

```js
import React from "react";
import Lottie from "react-lottie";
import data from "./Lottie/87736-car-animation.json";
import {getWindowDimensions} from './windowDimensions.js';

export default function App() {
  const defaultOptions = {
loop: true,
autoplay: true,
animationData: data,
rendererSettings: {
  preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice",
    },
  };

  return (
<div id="lottie">
// Here we use our conditional rendering
{ getWindowDimensions().width > 600 &&
  <Lottie
    options={defaultOptions}
    height={800}
    width={1000}
    style={{
      top: "30%",
      right: "10%",
      zIndex: -1,
      overflow: "hidden",
      position: "fixed",
    }}
  />
</div>
}
  );
}
```

This code will only render your lottie component if the window width is greater than 600. Of course, you could still use css conditional rendering and your code seems ok for that. Maybe try with `visibility: hidden` instead on your media query. Careful, you are defining an id `lottie` in  your react code which should be used as `#lottie` in your css. You are currently  using it as `.lottie` in your css which refers to a class. This is probably why your css aproach is not working.
Finally I would also take a look at what the classes you are adding to your lottie component refer to.  
Hope this gives you a place to start investigating from.
Here are some [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) about conditional rendering.

Comment: thanks so much, i have worked on the . to # in css and i would try out the conditional rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Your css won't affect your lottie because `.lottie` is a class but your lottie is defined as an id, so use `#lottie` instead:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #lottie {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in `<Lottie />` remove `d-none` and add  `d-lg-block d-md-block d-sm-none d-none` it'll do the trick